# Cheapest x86 machine with remote power mgmt?

Tags: mini-pc, embedded-systems

I am looking for a cheap x86 machine for learning OpenStack and other crap and I was wondering if such a system exists. The system should meet the following requirements:

- Under 100EUR including the price of RAM and "HDD" and VAT for items from outside EU if possible.
- RAM >= 2 GB (if price a bit higher, would like to have 4GB RAM).
- Compactable with [ironic](https://docs.openstack.org/ironic/latest/admin/drivers.html)
- Must be able to run headless.
- Must be able to run non-custom Linux distributions and OpenBSD preferable.

I understand that there might be some other talks how to achieve what I want, if so, please paste me the URL to it.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you considered a Raspberry PI?

Comment: Hi Bennet Yeo, yes. But rpi do not have mgmt board supported by ironic AND are ARM not x86 ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for new or used?

The cheapest new x86 PC's you can get without monitor from somewhat known brands are:

UP Core - https://up-shop.org/up-core/271-up-core.html

1-4 GB RAM, 16-64 GB eMMC storage, Intel Atom X5 Z8350, 99$USD for cheapest options

ASUS Computer Stick VivoStick - https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16883221244

2 GB RAM, 32 GB eMMC, Intel Atom X5 Z8350, 119$USD

Or you can shop for prebuilt Celeron systems on AliExpress, since there are plenty of options and you can also pick what hardware will be installed (RAM, SSD, CPU):

XCY Pocket Mini PC - https://ru.aliexpress.com/item/XCY-Intel-Celeron-1007U-10/32859512422.html

2 GB RAM, 16 GB SSD, Intel Celeron 1007U, 92$USD

Mini PC Celeron J1900 - https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Mini-PC-Celeron-J1900-Quad-Core-Windows-10-Dual-LAN-2-COM-Fanless-Mini-Computer-Celeron/32839489621.html

2GB RAM, 30 GB SSD, Intel Celeron N2810, 104$USD

Other than those options some used laptop might have more power in sub-100 price range, but you would need to choose carefully.

Comment: Yup, I was looking at those, almost bought some of these, but then I have realized, that they do not have IPMI or any other remote mgmt module...
it can be new or used, but preferably new, due to power consumption and possibly new will be smaller and with passive cooling :)